# Eager loading is not including the navigation property from my repository class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have the following method inside my repository class, to retrieve a `Session` object and the associated `Medicine object` (by defining Eager loading using the `.Include`) as shown below:-

```
public Session GetSession(int id)
        {
            return entities.Sessions.Include(d => d.Medicine).FirstOrDefault(d => d.SessionID == id);

        }
```

My action method which call the above repository method look as follow:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {

            try
            {
                //string desc;
                var s = repository.GetSession(id);

                repository.DeleteSession(s);

                repository.Save();
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = s.SessionID, description = s.Medicine.Name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
//code goes here
```

The problem i am facing is that after physically deleting the object using              `repository.Save();` ,, i will not be able to access the `Medicine navigation property` from the memory and the following exception will be raised *NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code* on `description = s.Medicine.Name` , while i can access the `s.SessionID` which will be avilable in the memory even after deleting the object, so does this means that the `Session` object which was deleted did not `Include` (did not eager load) the `Medicine` navigation property !!!?
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete an entity which has a relationship to another entity, Entity Framework will remove the relationship between those objects at the same time. You can solve the problem by creating the object for the Json result *before* you delete the entity:

```
var s = repository.GetSession(id);

var result = new { IsSuccess = "True", id = s.SessionID,
                   description = s.Medicine.Name };

repository.DeleteSession(s);
repository.Save();

return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If there is no reference from the session to Medicine in the database this won't help of course because `Include` won't return a related object. You have to handle this case separately (it would be only possible if the relationship is not required).

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, there is a foreign key at the session table (medicineId) that reference the PK of the Medicine table which is medicineID.